# Cannot display HTML string

Tags: android, python, html, webview

I am struggling with display string HTML in Android WebView.

On the server side, I downloaded a web page and escape HTML characters and quotes (I used Python):

```
my_string = html.escape(my_string, True)
```

On the Android client side: strings are unescaped by:

```
myString = StringEscapeUtils.unescapeHtml4(myString)
webview.loadData( myString, "text/html", "encoding");
```

However webview just display them as literal strings. Here are the result:

[image]

Edit: I add original string returned from server side:

> "&lt;!DOCTYPE html&gt; &lt;html
> lang=&quot;en&quot;&gt; &lt;head&gt; &lt;meta
> charset=&quot;utf-8&quot;&gt; &lt;meta
> http-equiv=&quot;X-UA-Compatible&quot;
> content=&quot;IE=edge&quot;&gt; &lt;meta
> name=&quot;viewport&quot;
> content=&quot;width=device-width,
> initial-scale=1.0&quot;&gt; &lt;meta
> name=&quot;description&quot;
> content=&quot;&quot;&gt;
> &lt;title&gt;Saulify&lt;/title&gt; &lt;!-- All the
> Favicons... --&gt; &lt;link rel=&quot;shortcut
> icon&quot;
> href=&quot;/static/favicon/favicon.ico&quot;&gt;
> &lt;link rel=&quot;apple-touch-icon&quot;
> sizes=&quot;57x57&quot;
> href=&quot;/static/favicon/apple-touch-icon-57x57.png&quot;&gt;
> &lt;link rel=&quot;apple-touch-icon&quot;
> sizes=&quot;114x114&quot;
> href=&quot;/static/favicon/apple-touch-icon-114x114.png&quot;&gt;
> &lt;link rel=&quot;apple-touch-icon&quot;
> sizes=&quot;72x72&quot;
> href=&quot;/static/favicon/apple-touch-icon-72x72.png&quot;&gt;
> &lt;link rel=&quot;apple-touch-icon&quot;
> sizes=&quot;144x144&quot;
> href=&quot;/static/favicon/apple-touch-icon-144x144.png&quot;&gt;
> &lt;link rel=&quot;apple-touch-icon&quot;
> sizes=&quot;60x60&quot;
> href=&quot;/static/favicon/apple-touch-icon-60x60.png&quot;&gt;
> &lt;link rel=&quot;apple-touch-icon&quot;
> sizes=&quot;120x120&quot;
> href=&quot;/static/favicon/apple-touch-icon-120x120.png&quot;&gt;
> &lt;link rel=&quot;apple-touch-icon&quot;
> sizes=&quot;76x76&quot;
> href=&quot;/static/favicon/apple-touch-icon-76x76.png&quot;&gt;
> &lt;link rel=&quot;apple-touch-icon&quot;
> sizes=&quot;152x152&quot;
> href=&quot;/static/favicon/apple-touch-icon-152x152.png&quot;&gt;
> &lt;link rel=&quot;apple-touch-icon&quot;
> sizes=&quot;180x180&quot;
> href=&quot;/static/favicon/apple-touch-icon-180x180.png&quot;&gt;
> &lt;link rel=&quot;icon&quot;
> type=&quot;image/png&quot;
> href=&quot;/static/favicon/favicon-192x192.png&quot;
> sizes=&quot;192x192&quot;&gt; &lt;link
> rel=&quot;icon&quot; type=&quot;image/png&quot;
> href=&quot;/static/favicon/favicon-160x160.png&quot;
> sizes=&quot;160x160&quot;&gt; &lt;link
> rel=&quot;icon&quot; type=&quot;image/png&quot;
> href=&quot;/static/favicon/favicon-96x96.png&quot;
> sizes=&quot;96x96&quot;&gt; &lt;link
> rel=&quot;icon&quot; type=&quot;image/png&quot;
> href=&quot;/static/favicon/favicon-16x16.png&quot;
> sizes=&quot;16x16&quot;&gt; &lt;link
> rel=&quot;icon&quot; type=&quot;image/png&quot;
> href=&quot;/static/favicon/favicon-32x32.png&quot;
> sizes=&quot;32x32&quot;&gt; &lt;meta
> name=&quot;msapplication-TileColor&quot;
> content=&quot;#da532c&quot;&gt; &lt;meta
> name=&quot;msapplication-TileImage&quot;
> content=&quot;/static/favicon/mstile-144x144.png&quot;&gt;
> &lt;meta name=&quot;msapplication-config&quot;
> content=&quot;/static/favicon/browserconfig.xml&quot;&gt;
> &lt;!-- External CSS --&gt; &lt;link
> rel=&quot;stylesheet&quot;
> href=&quot;https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css&quot;&gt;
> &lt;!-- External Fonts --&gt; &lt;link
> href=&quot;//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.2.0/css/font-awesome.min.css&quot;
> rel=&quot;stylesheet&quot;&gt; &lt;link
> href=&#x27;//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300,600&#x27;
> rel=&#x27;stylesheet&#x27;
> type=&#x27;text/css&#x27;&gt; &lt;link
> href=&#x27;//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lora:400,700&#x27;
> rel=&#x27;stylesheet&#x27;
> type=&#x27;text/css&#x27;&gt; &lt;!--[if lt IE
> 9]&gt; &lt;script
> src=&quot;//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/html5shiv/3.7.2/html5shiv.min.js&quot;&gt;&lt;/script&gt;
> &lt;script
> src=&quot;//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/respond.js/1.4.2/respond.min.js&quot;&gt;&lt;/script&gt;
> &lt;![endif]--&gt; &lt;!-- Site CSS --&gt;
> &lt;link rel=&quot;stylesheet&quot;
> type=&quot;text/css&quot;
> href=&quot;/static/css/style.css&quot;&gt; &lt;link
> rel=&quot;stylesheet&quot; type=&quot;text/css&quot;
> href=&quot;/static/css/glyphicon.css&quot;&gt;
> &lt;/head&gt; &lt;body&gt; &lt;div
> class=&quot;container article-page&quot;&gt; &lt;div
> class=&quot;row&quot;&gt; &lt;div
> class=&quot;col-md-8 col-md-offset-2&quot;&gt;
> &lt;h2&gt;&lt;a
> href=&quot;http://www.huffingtonpost.com/2015/03/22/ted-cruz-climate-change_n_6919002.html&quot;&gt;Gov.
> Jerry Brown Says Ted Cruz Is &amp;#39;Absolutely
> Unfit&amp;#39; To Run For Office Because Of Climate Change
> Views&lt;/a&gt;&lt;/h2&gt; &lt;h4&gt;Sam
> Levine&lt;/h4&gt; &lt;div
> class=&quot;article&quot;&gt; &lt;p&gt;California
> Gov. Jerry Brown (D) said on Sunday that Texas Sen. Ted Cruz (R-Texas)
> is &quot;absolutely unfit to be running for office&quot;
> because of his position on climate change.&lt;/p&gt;
> &lt;p&gt;&quot;I just came back from New Hampshire, where
> there&#x27;s snow and ice everywhere. My view on this is simple:
> Debates on this should follow science and should follow data, and many
> of the alarmists on global warming, they have a problem because the
> science doesn&#x27;t back them up,&quot; Cruz &lt;a
> href=&quot;https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=m0UJ_Sc0Udk&quot;&gt;said&lt;/a&gt;
> on &quot;Late Night with Seth Meyers&quot; last
> week.&lt;/p&gt; &lt;p&gt;To back up his claim, Cruz
> cited satellite data that has shown a lack of significant warming over
> the last 17 years. But Cruz&#x27;s reasoning &lt;a
> href=&quot;http://www.politifact.com/truth-o-meter/statements/2015/mar/20
> /ted-cruz/ted-cruzs-worlds-fire-not-last-17-years/&quot;&gt;has
> been debunked by Politifact&lt;/a&gt;, which has shown that
> scientists have ample evidence to believe that the climate will
> continue to warm.&lt;/p&gt; &lt;p&gt;&quot;What he
> said is absolutely false,” Brown said on &lt;a
> href=&quot;http://www.nbcnews.com/meet-the-press/california-governor-ted-cruz-
> unfit-be-running-n328046&quot;&gt;NBC&#x27;s
> &quot;Meet the Press.&quot;&lt;/a&gt; He added that
> &lt;a
> href=&quot;http://climate.nasa.gov/scientific-consensus/&quot;&gt;over
> 90 percent&lt;/a&gt; of scientists who study the climate agree
> that climate change is caused by human activity. &quot;That man
> betokens such a level of ignorance and a direct falsification of
> existing scientific data. It&#x27;s shocking, and I think that man
> has rendered himself absolutely unfit to be running for
> office,&quot; Brown said.&lt;/p&gt; &lt;p&gt;Brown
> added that climate change has &lt;a
> href=&quot;http://www.huffingtonpost.com/2015/03/06/california-drought-february-
> record_n_6820704.html?utm_hp_ref=california-drought&quot;&gt;caused
> droughts in his state&lt;/a&gt;, as well as severe cold and
> storms on the east coast.&lt;/p&gt; &lt;p&gt;While
> Cruz may have seen snow and ice everywhere in New Hampshire, data
> shows that the country is actually experiencing a &lt;a
> href=&quot;http://www.huffingtonpost.com/2015/02/19/cold-weather-
> winter_n_6713104.html&quot;&gt;warmer than
> average&lt;/a&gt; winter.&lt;/p&gt;
> &lt;p&gt;Brown’s criticism of Cruz comes one day before the
> Texas senator is set to announce a &lt;a
> href=&quot;http://www.huffingtonpost.com/2015/03/22
> /ted-cruz-2016_n_6917824.html&quot;&gt;presidential
> campaign&lt;/a&gt;. &lt;/p&gt; &lt;/div&gt;
> &lt;div class=&quot;original&quot;&gt; &lt;a
> href=&quot;http://www.huffingtonpost.com/2015/03/22/ted-cruz-climate-change_n_6919002.html&quot;&gt;VIEW
> ORIGINAL&lt;/a&gt; &lt;/div&gt; &lt;/div&gt;
> &lt;/div&gt; &lt;/div&gt; &lt;script
> src=&quot;//code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js&quot;&gt;&lt;/script&gt;
> &lt;script
> src=&quot;/static/js/modal.js&quot;&gt;&lt;/script&gt;
> &lt;script
> src=&quot;/static/js/bootbox.min.js&quot;&gt;&lt;/script&gt;
> &lt;script
> src=&quot;/static/js/site.js&quot;&gt;&lt;/script&gt; &lt;script&gt;
> (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i[&#x27;GoogleAnalyticsObject&#x27;]=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
> (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new
> Date();a=s.createElement(o),
> m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
> })(window,document,&#x27;script&#x27;,&#x27;//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js&#x27;,&#x27;ga&#x27;);
> ga(&#x27;create&#x27;, &#x27;UA-56257533-1&#x27;,
> &#x27;auto&#x27;); ga(&#x27;send&#x27;,
> &#x27;pageview&#x27;); &lt;/script&gt;
> &lt;/body&gt; &lt;/html&gt;"

Answer (score 69, accepted):

I have modified the code here:

```
public class test extends Activity {
    private WebView wv;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.test);
        wv = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.wv);
        String s = "&lt;!DOCTYPE html&gt; &lt;html lang=&quot;en&quot;&gt; &lt;head&gt; &lt;meta charset=&quot;utf-8&quot;&gt; &lt;meta http-equiv=&quot;X-UA-Compatible&quot; content=&quot;IE=edge&quot;&gt; &lt;meta name=&quot;viewport&quot; content=&quot;width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0&quot;&gt; &lt;meta name=&quot;description&quot; content=&quot;&quot;&gt; &lt;title&gt;Saulify&lt;/title&gt; &lt;!-- All the Favicons... --&gt; &lt;link rel=&quot;shortcut icon&quot; href=&quot;/static/favicon/favicon.ico&quot;&gt; &lt;link rel=&quot;apple-touch-icon&quot; sizes=&quot;57x57&quot; href=&quot;/static/favicon/apple-touch-icon-57x57.png&quot;&gt; &lt;link rel=&quot;apple-touch-icon&quot; sizes=&quot;114x114&quot; href=&quot;/static/favicon/apple-touch-icon-114x114.png&quot;&gt; &lt;link rel=&quot;apple-touch-icon&quot; sizes=&quot;72x72&quot; href=&quot;/static/favicon/apple-touch-icon-72x72.png&quot;&gt; &lt;link rel=&quot;apple-touch-icon&quot; sizes=&quot;144x144&quot; href=&quot;/static/favicon/apple-touch-icon-144x144.png&quot;&gt; &lt;link rel=&quot;apple-touch-icon&quot; sizes=&quot;60x60&quot; href=&quot;/static/favicon/apple-touch-icon-60x60.png&quot;&gt; &lt;link rel=&quot;apple-touch-icon&quot; sizes=&quot;120x120&quot; href=&quot;/static/favicon/apple-touch-icon-120x120.png&quot;&gt; &lt;link rel=&quot;apple-touch-icon&quot; sizes=&quot;76x76&quot; href=&quot;/static/favicon/apple-touch-icon-76x76.png&quot;&gt; &lt;link rel=&quot;apple-touch-icon&quot; sizes=&quot;152x152&quot; href=&quot;/static/favicon/apple-touch-icon-152x152.png&quot;&gt; &lt;link rel=&quot;apple-touch-icon&quot; sizes=&quot;180x180&quot; href=&quot;/static/favicon/apple-touch-icon-180x180.png&quot;&gt; &lt;link rel=&quot;icon&quot; type=&quot;image/png&quot; href=&quot;/static/favicon/favicon-192x192.png&quot; sizes=&quot;192x192&quot;&gt; &lt;link rel=&quot;icon&quot; type=&quot;image/png&quot; href=&quot;/static/favicon/favicon-160x160.png&quot; sizes=&quot;160x160&quot;&gt; &lt;link rel=&quot;icon&quot; type=&quot;image/png&quot; href=&quot;/static/favicon/favicon-96x96.png&quot; sizes=&quot;96x96&quot;&gt; &lt;link rel=&quot;icon&quot; type=&quot;image/png&quot; href=&quot;/static/favicon/favicon-16x16.png&quot; sizes=&quot;16x16&quot;&gt; &lt;link rel=&quot;icon&quot; type=&quot;image/png&quot; href=&quot;/static/favicon/favicon-32x32.png&quot; sizes=&quot;32x32&quot;&gt; &lt;meta name=&quot;msapplication-TileColor&quot; content=&quot;#da532c&quot;&gt; &lt;meta name=&quot;msapplication-TileImage&quot; content=&quot;/static/favicon/mstile-144x144.png&quot;&gt; &lt;meta name=&quot;msapplication-config&quot; content=&quot;/static/favicon/browserconfig.xml&quot;&gt; &lt;!-- External CSS --&gt; &lt;link rel=&quot;stylesheet&quot; href=&quot;https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css&quot;&gt; &lt;!-- External Fonts --&gt; &lt;link href=&quot;//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.2.0/css/font-awesome.min.css&quot; rel=&quot;stylesheet&quot;&gt; &lt;link href=&#x27;//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300,600&#x27; rel=&#x27;stylesheet&#x27; type=&#x27;text/css&#x27;&gt; &lt;link href=&#x27;//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lora:400,700&#x27; rel=&#x27;stylesheet&#x27; type=&#x27;text/css&#x27;&gt; &lt;!--[if lt IE 9]&gt; &lt;script src=&quot;//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/html5shiv/3.7.2/html5shiv.min.js&quot;&gt;&lt;/script&gt; &lt;script src=&quot;//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/respond.js/1.4.2/respond.min.js&quot;&gt;&lt;/script&gt; &lt;![endif]--&gt; &lt;!-- Site CSS --&gt; &lt;link rel=&quot;stylesheet&quot; type=&quot;text/css&quot; href=&quot;/static/css/style.css&quot;&gt; &lt;link rel=&quot;stylesheet&quot; type=&quot;text/css&quot; href=&quot;/static/css/glyphicon.css&quot;&gt; &lt;/head&gt; &lt;body&gt; &lt;div class=&quot;container article-page&quot;&gt; &lt;div class=&quot;row&quot;&gt; &lt;div class=&quot;col-md-8 col-md-offset-2&quot;&gt; &lt;h2&gt;&lt;a href=&quot;http://www.huffingtonpost.com/2015/03/22/ted-cruz-climate-change_n_6919002.html&quot;&gt;Gov. Jerry Brown Says Ted Cruz Is &amp;#39;Absolutely Unfit&amp;#39; To Run For Office Because Of Climate Change Views&lt;/a&gt;&lt;/h2&gt; &lt;h4&gt;Sam Levine&lt;/h4&gt; &lt;div class=&quot;article&quot;&gt; &lt;p&gt;California Gov. Jerry Brown (D) said on Sunday that Texas Sen. Ted Cruz (R-Texas) is &quot;absolutely unfit to be running for office&quot; because of his position on climate change.&lt;/p&gt; &lt;p&gt;&quot;I just came back from New Hampshire, where there&#x27;s snow and ice everywhere. My view on this is simple: Debates on this should follow science and should follow data, and many of the alarmists on global warming, they have a problem because the science doesn&#x27;t back them up,&quot; Cruz &lt;a href=&quot;https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=m0UJ_Sc0Udk&quot;&gt;said&lt;/a&gt; on &quot;Late Night with Seth Meyers&quot; last week.&lt;/p&gt; &lt;p&gt;To back up his claim, Cruz cited satellite data that has shown a lack of significant warming over the last 17 years. But Cruz&#x27;s reasoning &lt;a href=&quot;http://www.politifact.com/truth-o-meter/statements/2015/mar/20 /ted-cruz/ted-cruzs-worlds-fire-not-last-17-years/&quot;&gt;has been debunked by Politifact&lt;/a&gt;, which has shown that scientists have ample evidence to believe that the climate will continue to warm.&lt;/p&gt; &lt;p&gt;&quot;What he said is absolutely false,” Brown said on &lt;a href=&quot;http://www.nbcnews.com/meet-the-press/california-governor-ted-cruz- unfit-be-running-n328046&quot;&gt;NBC&#x27;s &quot;Meet the Press.&quot;&lt;/a&gt; He added that &lt;a href=&quot;http://climate.nasa.gov/scientific-consensus/&quot;&gt;over 90 percent&lt;/a&gt; of scientists who study the climate agree that climate change is caused by human activity. &quot;That man betokens such a level of ignorance and a direct falsification of existing scientific data. It&#x27;s shocking, and I think that man has rendered himself absolutely unfit to be running for office,&quot; Brown said.&lt;/p&gt; &lt;p&gt;Brown added that climate change has &lt;a href=&quot;http://www.huffingtonpost.com/2015/03/06/california-drought-february- record_n_6820704.html?utm_hp_ref=california-drought&quot;&gt;caused droughts in his state&lt;/a&gt;, as well as severe cold and storms on the east coast.&lt;/p&gt; &lt;p&gt;While Cruz may have seen snow and ice everywhere in New Hampshire, data shows that the country is actually experiencing a &lt;a href=&quot;http://www.huffingtonpost.com/2015/02/19/cold-weather- winter_n_6713104.html&quot;&gt;warmer than average&lt;/a&gt; winter.&lt;/p&gt; &lt;p&gt;Brown’s criticism of Cruz comes one day before the Texas senator is set to announce a &lt;a href=&quot;http://www.huffingtonpost.com/2015/03/22 /ted-cruz-2016_n_6917824.html&quot;&gt;presidential campaign&lt;/a&gt;. &lt;/p&gt; &lt;/div&gt; &lt;div class=&quot;original&quot;&gt; &lt;a href=&quot;http://www.huffingtonpost.com/2015/03/22/ted-cruz-climate-change_n_6919002.html&quot;&gt;VIEW ORIGINAL&lt;/a&gt; &lt;/div&gt; &lt;/div&gt; &lt;/div&gt; &lt;/div&gt; &lt;script src=&quot;//code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js&quot;&gt;&lt;/script&gt; &lt;script src=&quot;/static/js/modal.js&quot;&gt;&lt;/script&gt; &lt;script src=&quot;/static/js/bootbox.min.js&quot;&gt;&lt;/script&gt; &lt;script src=&quot;/static/js/site.js&quot;&gt;&lt;/script&gt; &lt;script&gt; (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i[&#x27;GoogleAnalyticsObject&#x27;]=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){ (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o), m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m) })(window,document,&#x27;script&#x27;,&#x27;//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js&#x27;,&#x27;ga&#x27;); ga(&#x27;create&#x27;, &#x27;UA-56257533-1&#x27;, &#x27;auto&#x27;); ga(&#x27;send&#x27;, &#x27;pageview&#x27;); &lt;/script&gt; &lt;/body&gt; &lt;/html&gt;";


        wv.loadData(stripHtml(s), "text/html", "UTF-8");

    }

    public String stripHtml(String html) {
        return Html.fromHtml(html).toString();
    }

}
```

[image]

Answer (score 13):

Try this code,

```
if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.N){
   yourtextview.setText(Html.fromHtml(yourstring,Html.FROM_HTML_MODE_LEGACY));
}
else {
   yourtextview.setText(Html.fromHtml(yourstring));
}
```

Comment: Smart test. Clever.

Answer (score 11):

Try this:

```
wv = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.wv);
String s = "You HTML string";
wv.loadData(stripHtml(s), "text/html", "UTF-8");

public String stripHtml(String html) {
    return Html.fromHtml(html).toString();
}
```